# Google finds thesis, but not indexed google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I have recently finished my thesis, and it has been uploaded to my university's e-thesis server roughly 4 weeks ago.

The thesis can be found via google, after I manually submitted the link to google.
Unfortunatly, the thesis is not found via google scholar. Many of my colleage's thesis (with very similar, standard format), which are at the same e-thesis server, are found via google scholar (and the google scholar link then points to that e-thesis server).

Is there any way I can make google scholar index my thesis?

Comment: Just wait a while. Google scholar is not as frequently updated as google's search index, but since it is aware of the e-thesis server, it'll surely appear at some point.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee: all the Google-Scholar's algorithms are pretty much machine-learning and heuristics.

Still, if your thesis' format is similar to what the other colleagues submitted, the chances are high it would be treated similarly.  Just wait a bit, as @nengel said.

If your thesis itself were *very similar*, it would be plagiarism: in this case, Google scholar would be right on not indexing your work (regardless of the algorithmic process that led to non-indexing).

Comment: The OP says the *format* of the thesis is the same, not the content. That's not plagiarism.

Comment: I don't think it's very nice to imply that someone has plagiarised their thesis, that's all.

Comment: Google scholar is indexing the same document from different sources. Why do you think they got a mechanism to test for plagiarism and exclude such documents?

Comment: @DSVA I never definitely implied that GS does have this mechanism. But sometimes I think it might have some. I know that some people plagiarized my work, but I don't see their results in GS.

Comment: @astronat I adapted the answer grammatically to make it "nicer".